# 7zip command line equivalent of these settings?

Tags: command-line, 7-zip

I have a huge folder (360GB) of log files on a unix system, which I would like to have zipped up with PPMd, more specifically, these GUI settings.

[image]

I've read through the 7zip instructions but I really can't seem to make sense of them, there seems to be a -M option, and a -o option, but I don't see any options for Word size, and Dictionary size

Does anyone know the equivalent command line settings for this configuration? Does anyone have a good reference or a way to convert these settings?

Comment: They are referenced quite well in the official documentation. What did you try that did not work ?

Comment: I'm using `7za a -t7z -m0=PPMd:mem=32M:o=8 logs.7z "/path/to/huge/logfolder/"` however I belive i'm getting a much larger filesize than I would with the GUI settings

Comment: @overmind, I don't believe they are referenced very well at all in the official documentation, I see it says -o "sets the model orderfor PPMd" without explaining what model order is. It also says mem "Sets size of used memory for PPMd", again, without actually explaining what it does. Furthermore, I also can't seem to find anything relating to "dictionary size" or "word size" for PPMd in the docs, which seem to be the main drop-downs in the GUI. I hope you understand why I am confused

Comment: I understand, probably we're looking at different documentations, I remember having a pdf with all command references. I'll see if I find it. As for the compression difference I cam make some testing.

Comment: Command line in your comment vs your GUI settings: 29.3 MB (30,818,915 bytes) vs 40.1 MB (42,145,962 bytes). Used for testing: 1GB firewall log file.